# Why do we need to restart IIS after copied DLLs into Assembly

Tags: sharepoint, iis, gac

Whenever we copy Dlls into assembly folder we need to restart IIS. It takes more time and we need to do it for every changes. So it is full of wasting time.

Is there any alternative option instead of restarting IIS.

I am working in Sharepoint 2007, windows server 2008

Answer (score 6):

We restart the IIS to reset Application pool as lot of things in SharePoint are cached. The alternative option is you can recycle the application pool of the application for which you have deployed the WSP or DLLs

Comment: Actually it's not SharePoint functionality, but a more low level .NET caching mechanism.

Comment: @Vladi in case of sharepoint it works for resetting other cached items created by w3wp.exe which is required after any new updates in code thats why i had not written a generic term as .net aching mechanism but at the end everything in SharePoint is governed by .Net framework

Comment: Yes, but when developing, you usually just need to reload the DLL. We always compile directly into BIN and the worker process just picks it up. Of course it does not work for timer jobs or event receivers, but these are in the minority anyway.

Comment: @Vladi Minority things are also included when you are trying to suggest a generic answer where you don't know whats the users exact requirement is whether he has included any timer job or event handler  code in dll. My point is that you should avoid negative voting unless you are completely sure. Any way the solution proposed by me for his question is 100% correct

Comment: Who said anything about negative voting?

Answer (score 0):

Its the ASP.NET behavior:
[Asp.net Reinstalling a DLL into the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711/asp-net-reinstalling-a-dll-into-the-gac)

Answer (score 0):

reset Application pool as lot of things are  cached & all sessions connected to your Web server (including Internet, FTP, SMTP, and NNTP) are dropped