# Updating an existing ASPX application without success

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I've a little problem, with a ASPX .NET application that I'm updating.

After having updated the DLL and the ASPX files on the production server, my application is still running not modified.

Is there a method to force IIS reloading the application without restarting the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711/asp-net-reinstalling-a-dll-into-the-gac

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602186/how-to-update-asp-net-site-dll-without-stopping-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the **app_offline.htm** file on the root of your www, then make your modifications, then delete it (or just rename it)

If you all ready update your dlls, create the app_offline.htm, then just make any small update to web.config (by just add an empty line) save the web.config, then delete the app_offline.htm (or just rename it)

the app_offline.htm, force your application to stop and restart and then the dot net see the changes and recompile it.

When the app_offline.htm is open, all pages show the content of this file, so you can place inside of this file any messages to your viewers.

Visual studio make the same trick when its starts with this file.